# How do you update an array value in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, node.js, npm, npm-request

JSON Data:

```
{
  "role": [ "Jungle", "Mid" ],
  "total_wins": 0
}
```

This is the request I'm using, using npm request.

```
   request({
          uri: uri, 
          method: "PATCH", 
          json: {
            "total_wins": 1, 
            "role": ["Support", "Top"]
          }
   });
```

output:

```
{
  "role": [ "Jungle", "Mid" ],
  "total_wins": 1
}
```

expected:

```
{
  "role": [ "Support", "Top" ],
  "total_wins": 1
}
```

I'm not sure whats happening, the PATCH request produces no errors, but it doesn't change any data for role, yet it changes the total_wins to 1.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I'm not sure, it didn't catch any errors

Comment: Are you sending this with a content-type of application/json? In that case it's entirely undefined what happens (application/json is not defined for PATCH).

Comment: what are you saying the solution should be then? ._. cause I don't know what application/json is. im using node.js

Comment: check your controller and params, did it permit role?, also you can share your controller in the questions

Comment: @icemelt omg... youre a genius i forgot to let my controller accept arrays. I haven't used rails in a while and forgot thats a thing

Answer (score 0):

check your controller and params, did it permit role?